# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'metaClass': Set this property value or disable dependency checking for this bean groovy

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I am rewriting my spring java code in groovy. but while running I am getting exception while spring registering my class as bean
below is my stack trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.data.MyTestClass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'metaClass': Set this property value or disable dependency checking for this bean.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.checkDependencies(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
        at com.metricstream.systemi.ext.infolet.AbstractInfoletService.autowireThis(AbstractInfoletService.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Below is my code

```
package org.data
class MyTestClass extends AbstractService  {

    @Inject
    private SyncImpl info;

    /**
     * Public constructor to initialize.
     */
    public MyTestClass() {

        super(MyTestClass.class.getName(), MyTestClass.class.getSimpleName(), PluginInfo.NAME);
        PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(MyTestClass.class);
        for(PropertyDescriptor pDesc : descriptors){
            if(pDesc.getName().equals("metaClass")) continue;
        }

}}
```

is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: @aristotll sorry for late reply have added the code